# Is it possible to have full LAN access through a meterpreter session? e.g. for a MITM attack

Tags: man-in-the-middle, meterpreter

Is it possible to perform a MITM Attack through a compromised Windows Machine in a internal LAN? 
How would be the attacker's scenario? How to do this?

Comment: It looks like you're asking for a "how to hack" tutorial which is outside the scope of this site. Please rephrase your question in a way that we can give a concise and specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course.

From a meterpreter session you could run [post modules](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/post-module-reference/) that run on the compromised machine.

You could also use [port forwarding](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/portfwd/) in the case you want to connect to Remote Desktop and the port itself isn't accessible from the attacker's machine.

Tools like [nighthawk](https://github.com/klemenb/nighthawk) can be used to achieve ARP spoofing (MITM).

It all depends on how stealthy you need to be. Note this is a brief overview and I haven't gone into any depth on these items as your question seems very broad. Feel free to ask a new question covering only a specific item, then link back to this as reference.